# How to make this code more effective so it does not print all results, just the ones that do not match conditional statement?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

So in the imported data, it reads with a bunch of different columns of different data types and I had to use certain columns data to make sure the listed rate in the data set matched with the rate I checked it against in the conditional statement. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Whenever I print the results, it prints all of the accounts even if they do match with the interest rates, is this because of using ".all( )"?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_pickle("data.pkl")
data.head()

def core_group():
    core_risk_1 = data.groupby(["pgroup", "pricing_risk_level"]).get_group(("CORE", "Risk Level 1"))
    if (core_risk_1["booked_int_rt"] != 0.0999).any():
        print(core_risk_1[["account_id", "pricing_risk_level", "booked_int_rate"]])

    core_risk_2 = data.groupby(["pgroup", "pricing_risk_level"]).get_group(("CORE", "Risk Level 2"))
    if (core_risk_2["booked_int_rt"] != 0.1199).any():
        print(core_risk_2[["account_id", "pricing_risk_level", "booked_int_rate"]])

    core_risk_3 = data.groupby(["pgroup", "pricing_risk_level"]).get_group(("CORE", "Risk Level 3"))
    if (core_risk_3["booked_int_rt"] != 0.1399).any():
        print(core_risk_3[["account_id", "pricing_risk_level", "booked_int_rate"]])

    core_risk_4 = data.groupby(["pgroup", "pricing_risk_level"]).get_group(("CORE", "Risk Level 4"))
    if (core_risk_4["booked_int_rt"] != 0.1499).any():
        print(core_risk_4[["account_id", "pricing_risk_level", "booked_int_rate"]])


core_group()
```

Comment: It prints everything because you have not filtered your frame. Also, you do not need the `if` statements. you can just boolean index: `core_risk_1[(core_risk_1["booked_int_rt"] != 0.0999).any()]`

Answer (score 0):

With .loc you can filter the rows that meet certain criteria. For example:

```
 core_risk_1 = core_risk_1.loc[core_risk_1["booked_int_rt"] != 0.0999, ["account_id", "pricing_risk_level", "booked_int_rate"]]
 if 0 < len(core_risk_1):
     print(core_risk_1])
```